# Curl not working in wp

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I have this request in wordpress,

```
        $url = $this->apiUrl . '/' . $url;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'X-Client: PHP ' . phpversion()
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ":" . $this->apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        switch ($httpVerb) {
            case 'post':
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                if ($data) {
                    $encoded = json_encode($data);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded);
                }
                break;
        }
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        echo json_encode(curl_getinfo($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
```

And this is the response

```
 {"url":"https:\/\/api.paylike.io\/cards\/5a05ba1d752c916c2607c5fb","content_type":null,"http_code":400,"header_size":435,"request_size":242,"filetime":-1,"ssl_verify_result":0,"redirect_count":0,"total_time":0.395293,"namelookup_time":0.01238,"connect_time":0.01387,"pretransfer_time":0.031095,"size_upload":0,"size_download":0,"speed_download":0,"speed_upload":0,"download_content_length":-1,"upload_content_length":-1,"starttransfer_time":0.395242,"redirect_time":0,"redirect_url":"","primary_ip":"104.20.8.147","certinfo":[],"primary_port":443,"local_ip":"138.68.167.102","local_port":45414}
```

The link is ok, but I don't know why do I get an 400 error, try accessing the page and see that is working : 
    https://api.paylike.io/cards/5a05ba1d752c916c2607c5fb

So where is the error, does wordpress have some limitation ? I tried this code outside of wordpress, and it works. Also I tried spootify my curl, but no results ...

Comment: I think your issue is here `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, ":" . $this->apiKey);`, You probably have to pass the key alone or user/key seperated by a colon. The colon here alone with the key seems odd.

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` should get you a lot more info. Your request might be totally fine, and the server is just rejecting it for other reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly check if the curl is enabled in your system or server. You can check it by using a simple page with this code.

phpinfo();

If curl is enabled it will show there. If its not enabled enable it.

Next check for the curl errors and clear it. Just add this code after the curl_exec($ch);

'Error Details: ' . curl_error($ch);
It will show you the error.

Comment: So, i’ve checked phpinfo, and curl is enabled, and also curl_error($ch) does not show me anything